# How to limit service rate through API gateway Apache APISIX?

Tags: api, limit, api-gateway, apache-apisix

To prevent malicious attacks, it is necessary to limit the speed of the client. How to implement it through APISIX?

Answer (score 0):

Various plugins have been implemented in APISIX. To solve your problem, you can refer to Traffic Control plugins.
More information: https://apisix.apache.org/plugins/#Traffic

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this by using the `limit-count` plugin. Below is an example for limiting the count to be two  requests in time window of sixty seconds; if it is increased over that in sixty seconds, it will return 503 as the error code.

```
curl -i http://127.0.0.1:9180/apisix/admin/services/1 \
-H 'X-API-KEY: edd1c9f034335f136f87ad84b625c8f1' -X PUT -d '
{
    "plugins": {
        "limit-count": {
            "count": 2,
            "time_window": 60,
            "rejected_code": 503,
            "key": "remote_addr",
            "group": "services_1#1640140620"
        }
    },
    "upstream": {
        "type": "roundrobin",
        "nodes": {
            "127.0.0.1:1980": 1
        }
    }
}'
```